# pgloader MySQL to Postgres: Disable FK for specified tables

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql, migration, pgloader

I'm trying to migrate `mysql` database to `postgres` using [pgloader](https://pgloader.io/).
Some tables in the current `mysql` database have foreign keys, but referential integrity is broken (based on data in those tables). I need to ignore FK constraint for those tables.

There is an option to disable foreign keys for all tables while migrating the database

```
 WITH no foreign keys
```

But I need to disable FK-s only for a specified list of tables and preserve FK-s for all other tables. I can't find anything related to this case in the documentation.

How it could be achieved?

The only option I've found for now - is to migrate the database in two steps:

1. migrate all tables excluding those for which FK-s should be ignored
2. migrate only tables for which FK-s should be ignored with `no foreign keys` option

Is there a simpler way?

Comment: Why don't you just drop FK constraint where it is known to be violated?

Comment: Yeah, I ended up with dropping FK constraints